# Placement of detail disclosure indicator

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using a disclosureindicator to show detail description of my tableview cells. I use

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator]
```

to invoke the system indicator. My question is how can I customize the placement? Currently it is ~10 px from right and I would like to place it 20 px from right margin of the screen. Can I set it programmatically or I have to place a custom image?
Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the standard view placements, you will have make your own assets and place them yourself using IB or with:

```
[cell addSubView:myCustomDisclosureView];
```

Comment: Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8 you can play with `layoutMargins`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIEdgeInsets layoutMargins = self.tableView.layoutMargins;
    layoutMargins.right = 20.0f;

    self.tableView.layoutMargins = layoutMargins;
}
```